# Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server:SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:self-signed certificate]

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I'm creating instance of SQL Server in a Docker container.

```bash
$ sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Adminxyz22#" -p 1433:1433 --name sql3  -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
bd7603e0df04a9ec23cfb089ee43bf5723ab4f1c881aefaf896c9ef11d2d909f
```

When I do the `sudo docker ps`

```bash
$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                        PORTS                                            NAMES
285722569f6e   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   9 minutes ago    Exited (0) 6 minutes ago
```

Now I'm trying to connect to Docker container SQL Server using sqlcmd I get this error:

```bash
sqlcmd -S localhost,1433 -U SA -P "Adminxyz22#"
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server : SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:self-signed certificate].
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection. For solutions related to encryption errors, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2226722.
```

When I login into docker container and execute sqlcmd it is working fine.

```bash
$ sudo docker exec -it bd7603e0df04 /bin/bash
mssql@bd7603e0df04:/$ /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "Adminxyz22#"
1>
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Aside... `SA_PASSWORD` is a deprecated environment variable for setting the sa password. Whilst it still works - for now - you should transition to using the `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` environment variable as shown in the [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server).

Comment: Unless you manually install an Organization-signed or CA-signed certificate then SQL Server instances use self-signed certificates for their TLS encrypted connections. Have a read through the _Encrypt = true, by default_ section of [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228) so see what alternatives you have available to you.

Comment: Assuming you don't care about security and want to just blindly trust the certificate, add the `-C` parameter to `sqlcmd`

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface your comment worked. care to post about the answer?

Comment: @Charlieface With a development box or student learning edition, local security won't be the issue it will be in a production environment.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill Then why use encryption at all? It just creates unnecessary headache for no extra security if you just blindly trust.

Comment: @Charlieface in that case, can you recommend any articles in configuring a SQL Server instance with a certificate, on macOS?

Comment: Instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-security?view=sql-server-ver16#encrypt-connections-to-sql-server-linux-containers use a proper CA certificate instead of a self-signed one.

Comment: @Charlieface "Then why use encryption at all?" I can't figure out how to use sqlcmd without encryption. I have tried a .odbc.ini.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill Set the server to Force Encrytion Off and it should just work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-sql-server-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16#step-2-configure-encryption-settings-in-sql-server and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-and-client-encryption-summary?view=sql-server-ver16